# Turn a Rect into one central point

Tags: java, opencv

I am currently using OpenCV to create a system which detects whether vehicles are in certain zones. So far, I've got to the point where a `Rect` is drawn around each vehicle. My next step is to find the central points of these rectangles and see whether that falls within a particular zone.

I realise that the best way of doing this is probably to find the coordinates of the `Rect`'s four corners and then take an average `x` and average `y`-coordinate to find the coordinates for the central point. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Is there some function which lets me access OpenCV's `Rect` coordinates directly?

Answer (score 1):

Edit to original: As was pointed out, we cannot use '+' operator directly on tl() and br().

Use this instead to get the center of a rectangle:

```
Point p1 = new Point(100, 100);
Point p2 = new Point(600, 800);
Rect myrect = new Rect(p1, p2);
System.out.println(String.format("Rectangle: %s", myrect));

Point centroid = new Point(myrect.x + 0.5*(myrect.width), myrect.y + 0.5*(myrect.height));
System.out.println(String.format("centroid: %s", centroid));
```

This prints:

```
Rectangle: {100, 100, 500x700}
centroid: {350.0, 450.0}
```

Old answer:

[Use rect's methods:

```
tl ()
br ()
```

to get the top left and bottom right points, respectively.]

If you did want to use tl, br methods you can do:

```
Point anotherCentroid = new Point(0.5 * (myrect.br().x + myrect.tl().x), 0.5 * (myrect.br().y + myrect.tl().y));
```

Comment: But how do I find the central point from these? It seems that the `+` operator is not allowed for use with `tl` and `br`...

Comment: afaik "+" is allowed for cv::Point but "/" might be not allowed. try 0.5f*(rect.tl() + rect.br())

Comment: On my phone so I can't verify, but you should be able to do: Point centroid = new Point(0.5*(rect.br() + rect.tl()))

Comment: You can also do: rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height to grab the rectangle's fields and do the arithmetic.

Comment: @Micka I get this error when I try to add the two Points "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Point"

Comment: @Scott Thanks, but I get the same problem again. "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) org.opencv.core.Point, org.opencv.core.Point"

Comment: You can definitely add the fields rect.x + rect.width

Comment: which OpenCV version?